# SQL WHERE filter on two integers, is it faster by conversion to char or a combined integer?

Tags: sql, sql-server

I have a table with a primary key made of two 32bit integers. I want to filter by an explicit list of these, and want to know the fastest approach. There are 3 ways I can think of.
My question simply is: *Which method is the fastest out of the second method or the third method?*
**1st method** I do not want to use because if I have many to list (only filtering for 2 rows in this example), it gets messy, or need a temp table, so not as concise:

```
select *
from [table]
where
    (
        ([int1] = 123 and [int2] = 456)
        OR ([int1] = 654 and [int2] = 321)
        --etc
    )
```

**2nd method** convert to varchar

```
select *
from [table]
where convert(varchar(10), [int1]) + ',' + convert(varchar(10), [int2]) IN ('123,456','654,321')
```

**3rd method** combine two 32bit integers to single 64bit integer

```
select *
from [table]
where convert(bigint, [int1]) * 4294967296 + [int2] IN (528280977864,2808908611905)
```

---

**Edit**
Thanks to suggestion from Aron, I have tried using statistics - these are the results on a table with > 1 million rows, average from 10 trials each:

```
Time Statistics               method 1  method 2    method 3
  Client processing time        22.1    2.7         2.9
  Total execution time          300.5   1099.8      1317.3
  Wait time on server replies   278.4   1097.1      1314.4
```

So really querying on them as is is the fastest by far, but if I did pick between the second or third method, then varchar is faster (which surprises me).

Comment: Should 2nd method be `...IN ('123456','456123')` ?

Comment: Is it too snarky to suggest that you turn on statistics and do some testing?

Comment: @Aron no - please feel free to offer advice like that. I haven't used statistics before, and not sure I have access to turn them on. But thank you for the keyword, I will see what google will teach me on that subject.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Your first method:

```
select *
from [table]
where ([int1] = 123 and [int2] = 456) OR
       [int1] = 654 and [int2] = 321) OR
        --etc
      )
```

Should be the fastest because it can take advantage of an index on `(int1, int2)`.  Perhaps the fastest method for a large list is to store the pairs in a temporary table with an index (clustered or unclustered) on `int1` and `int2`.

I would shy away from playing around with the values.  The bulk of the effort of the query is reading the data pages.  Slight variations in comparison logic will have little impact on the query.

Answer (score 1):

Maybe you need to give a better example?

I tried your example and performance looks all good. a bigger number of the result set can predict better? try using estimated plan.

```
create table #table (int1 int,int2 int)
insert into #table values(123,456);
insert into #table values(654,321);



select *
from #table
where
    (
          ([int1] = 123 and [int2] = 456)
        OR  ([int1] = 654 and [int2] = 321)
    )


    select *
    from #table
    where convert(varchar(10), [int1]) +'-'+ convert(varchar(10), [int2]) IN ('123-456','654-321')


    select *
    from #table
    where convert(bigint, [int1]) * 4294967296 + [int2] IN (528280977864,2808908611905)

    --drop table #table
```

will give almost same estimated cost. 33% each query...

[image]

Comment: Hi yes this is a simplistic example. It needs to be scalable to filter on a table with millions of rows. I am hoping someone will have done a test like this already - or anyway I will try spend some time over the next couple of weeks and learn how to use profiler, and get some stats.

Answer (score 0):

The 1st method that you dont want to use because of its messy, seems to be the fastest way, just put them on two columns and index them. 
  Speed of queries in SQL doesn't depend on the number of fields queried or complexity of queries, it only depends on how you use its index.